# How to create an observable in RxJS which waits for 2 observables ( in sequence) , then acts , and then waits for those 2 again in sequendce

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm struggling with a specific scenario for which I was hoping to use RxJS :

There are two observables which should trigger in sequence for a value to be registered  :

1. An observable representing a  user pressing a button
2. An observable representing a  device returning it's next value

After the user presses the button, it should wait until the device returns it's next value, then this value should be captured and processed. After that, it should again wait for the same sequence of events.

I found that it works once if I use concat, and I complete the observables upon receiving the button action and the device's value.

However, after the observables complete I can't use them anymore for subsequent actions.

I also found that I could use `zip`, which would trigger after both observables return their next() , but then the order isn't guaranteed ( it won't return the next value after the button was pressed, it will emit the value that was emitted in the meantime).

What would be the best-practice solution for this case ?

```
import { Observable, Subject, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { concat, repeat, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let user: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
let device: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

user.pipe(concat(device)).subscribe(() => {
    console.log("both called");
});


setInterval(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        user.complete();
        console.log("user action executed");
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        device.next(new Date().getSeconds());
        console.log("device value sent");
        device.complete();
    }, 5000);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what your 2nd observable is and how it is triggered. Could you create a stackblitz draft or share some pseudocode here?

Comment: `forkJoin` perhaps?

Comment: It looks like you could use just `concat(X$, Y$).pipe(repeat())` but I don't think I understand your use case completely.

Comment: It can't be `forkJoin`, as it needs a repeat and it's most likely not a `concat-repeat`, as the button click Observable probably wont complete. I think, it could be a `click$.pipe( exhaustMap(() => device$.pipe(take(1)) ) )`. Though we obviously need some more details here — so lets not confuse our dear OP in advance :P (myself in the first place)

Comment: what you definitely could do is call a function on each call of the two observalbes to set a boolean to true if both are true trigger the 3 rd one and set them back to false quite roundabout but definitely possible if thers no specific method for it

Comment: I've added a code sample to clarify what I'm doing currently with concat ( setInterval & setTimeout is just for testing it easily here ) .
What you notice when you run this is that works the first time, but afterwards it doesn't trigger anymore because it completed.

However, I need to have them completed as otherwise it doesn't work with concat at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exhaustMap` will let you listen to another stream while ignoring consequent events from the source stream:

```js
const { fromEvent, timer, Subject } = rxjs;
const { exhaustMap, take } = rxjs.operators;

// mock device$ will output every 3 seconds
const device$ = new Subject();
timer(0, 3000).subscribe(device$);
device$.subscribe(console.log); // output device ticking

// listen to button clicks
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const click$ = fromEvent(btn, 'click');
click$.pipe(
  // when a button is clicked -- we start listening
  // for the next event on the device$
  // until then we don't react to click$
  exhaustMap(() => device$.pipe(take(1)))
).subscribe(value => {
  console.log('Clicked at ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Clicker</button>
```

Heres an illustration of what's going on

[image: exhaustMap illustration]

Play with the [`exhaustMap` operator here](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/exhaustMap/).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can switchMap and return another observable.

```js
const { of, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, delay } = rxjs.operators;

fromEvent(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click').pipe(
    switchMap(e => of('some value').pipe(delay(1000)))
  )
  .subscribe(val => { console.log(val) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```